# Recovering LVM RAID-1 on different computer with only one drive?

Tags: linux, lvm, raid1, data-recovery

I have a drive out of an old LVM RAID-1 that's been sitting for a while.  I think the array contained a bunch of my photos from years ago (archived online) but I'd like to get at the original data and copy it to my new NAS.

This RAID has never been active on any machine I currently own, so I don't have any configuration files for it beyond what was stored on the drive itself (which I can't seem to mount to get access) so I can't just start it in "degraded" mode.

I can't seem to figure out how to mount the drive under my current Ubuntu system.

EDIT: The drive is fine, it was pulled during an upgrade and never put back into service.  IIRC there is an LVM group, then set up as a RAID-1. Not very familiar with using LVM: this is my first and only RAID I've ever made. I'll try the posted stuff tonight and see what I can get.

Comment: Please clarify first!  What debugging steps have you performed and at which step are you lost? Is the drive dead or still alive? If alive; does it have a partition table or not? Are you familiar with the LVM commands `pvscan` `vgscan` `lvscan` `lvchange` and their options?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to initialize volume group

```
# vgscan
# vgchange -ay
```

After that you can try the following commands to see what it has found

```
# pvdisplay
# vgdisplay
# lvdisplay
```